# issue with alert dialog box, due to it not recognizing the initiation of the alert box

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a dialog box which will show when an image is clicked but there seems to be a few issues with my code. The code is shown below. I have done the import for the dialog box but it doesn't seem to work as there is an error when initiating a new dialog box.

```
 ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Blah blah blah.\n Fine pring.\n Do you accept all our terms and conditions?")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("Terms of Service")
            .setNeutralButton("back", this)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create();

            ad.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Always have to be careful to read the "fine pring."

Comment: `The constructor AlertDialog.Builder (new View.onClickListener(){}) is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your reference to `this` on the line

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.builder(this)
```

is actually referring to the anonymous inner class `View.OnClickListener` which does NOT extend Context. So, just above your

```
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

put something to the effect of

```
final Context context = this;
```

and then change the aforemention builder call to read

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.builder(context)
```

i.e.

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
final Context context = this;
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setMessage("Blah blah blah.\n Fine pring.\n Do you accept all our terms and conditions?")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("Terms of Service")
        .setNeutralButton("back", this)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .create();

        ad.show();
    }
});
```

And I am making the (perhaps lofty) assumption that that block of code does indeed reside within a class that does in fact extend Context.

Comment: this has worked perfectly, I actually uncovered the problem myself but this is along the same lines as what I have now. So thanks